# Go: pop from a map

Tags: dictionary, go

Is there an existing function where we can pop a (key,value) pair from a map in GO? I use the word pop instead of remove because a pop would re-arrange the elements after the index where the (key,value) was removed.

As an example the following code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    mapp := make(map[int]int)
    fmt.Println("before removal:")

    for i := 1; i < 7; i++ {
        mapp[i] = i
    }
    fmt.Println(mapp)
    delete(mapp, 2)
    fmt.Println("\nafter the removal:")
    for i := 1; i < 7; i++ {
        fmt.Println(i, mapp[i])
    }

}
```

Produces the following output:

```
before removal:
map[1:1 2:2 3:3 4:4 5:5 6:6]

after the removal:
1 1
2 0
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
```

We notice that index location 2 is empty. I would like the output to be the following:

```
before removal:
map[1:1 2:2 3:3 4:4 5:5 6:6]

after the removal:
1 1
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
```

Is this functionality already in Go or would I have to implement it?

Comment: You are asking for the entire key:value relationship of the map to change every time you "pop". Using a map as an underlying data structure is certainly not the right way to go.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you're asking for a list that can have random items removed and remain sorted (or keep its original order, even if that isn't a sorted order). I'm not yet sure what you want that for, though. If you post a higher-level question about the general task you're trying to do (i.e., about the problem rather than about a proposed solution), we might be able to add something helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you are misunderstanding what a `map` is and how it works. You should not see it as an "array with gaps", but as a classic [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

And to answer your question, when you use `delete()`, the value is deleted from the `map`, the problem is how you iterate over the "values" of the map.

To help you understand:

```
mapp := make(map[int]int)
fmt.Println(2, mapp[2])
```

will print

```
2 0
```

Why ? Simply because when the requested key doesn't exist, we get the value type's *zero value*. In this case the value type is int, so the zero value is 0.

So, you want to see if a key exists in the map before printing it and you have to use two-value assignment, like that:

```
for i := 1; i < 7; i++ {
    if value, exists := mapp[i]; exists {
        fmt.Println(i, value)
    }
}
```

and it will print

```
1 1
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
```

Not really what you want, but the closer you can get directly with `map`s.
You can have a look at [this blog post](http://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action) for more information and examples.

If you really want to have an array where you can remove values, see Verran's answer and use slices instead.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Go documentation](http://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action):

`When iterating over a map with a range loop, the iteration order is not specified and is not guaranteed to be the same from one iteration to the next.`

From this, it follows that there would be no way to automatically move a value up one position to fill a gap, since the key can be in a different iteration position each time you look at the values and theres no guarantee that the value mapped to `2` will slide up to `1`.

If you want to do something like this, you will have to manually shift everything down one key value, something like:

```
for key := 2; key < len(map)-1; key++ {
    map[key] = map[key+1]
}
```

Alternatively, you could use slices and if you know the index you need to "pop", create a new slice that omits the value:

```
value := slice[2]
slice = copy(slice[:2], slice[2+1:])
```